# Sencha Touch itemtap Detailsview

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

i'm getting mad with this one,
I have a list in sencha touch 2, and i have a function in my `controller` file, that control the tap on the list and create a new view with the information, here's the `controller` file code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Details', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

config: {
    refs: {
         placesContainer:'placesContainer'
    },
    control: {
         'placesContainer places list':{
             itemtap: function(list,index,target,record) {
                 console.log("item "+record.get('name')+" pigiato");
                 var detailsView = Ext.create('MyApp.view.Details');
                 this.getPlacesContainer().push(detailsView);
                 detailsView.setData(record.data);
                 detailsView.getAt(0).setData(record.data); // will set data to first component in items array
                 detailsView.getAt(1).setData(record.data); // will set data to second component in items array
                 detailsView.getAt(2).setData(record.data); // will set data to second component in items array
             }
         }
    }
}
```

});

Now... How can i specify and set the title of my Details View with the name of the list item tapped?? someone can help?? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like this

```
var detailsView = Ext.create('MyApp.view.Details', {
  title: record.get('name')
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It was easy, i was close....The issue is that i'm not a javascript programmer, that's the problem... By the way, thank you! So i can specify other information or config for my detailsview, below the title string, right?
`var detailsView = Ext.create('MyApp.view.Details', {
 title: record.get('name'),
 scrollable:true,
 styleHtmlContent:true,
        styleHtmlCls:'details',
});`

Comment: Yes, you can basically pass along a config object.

Comment: Can i ask you the last things?
i have to pull my store variable like `name` into my detailsview,
with this string: `detailsView.getAt(0).setData(record.data);`
i can pull the data from a panel inside my view, but why is not working in a carousel view?